# Unable to connect to web server 'https' in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, iis, https

I have two projects for the API and UI side of my project.
On the UI side, I want to see the change I made with "ctrl + shift + w" on index.cshtml, but I get the error in the screenshot below.

There are errors I receive on the visual studio side and in the microsoft visual studio debug console.
Can you help me please?

[image: visual studio]

[image: visual studio debug console]

Sometimes I get errors like the one below.

[image: visual studio]

According to my research, I deleted launchsettings.json in the Properties folder of the UI project and added it again, but it did not work.

When I came to the debug properties of the project, I examined the http, https and IIS sections. Here, in the https section, these addresses were written as https://localhost:7069;http://localhost:5007.

For testing purposes, I opened the IIS side and copied the localhost address there and pasted it into the https section. It worked this time, but I still viewed the swagger page. This was not the page I wanted. Below is the screenshot.

[image: Debug Properties]
[image: Continue from the page]

Also, there is no place where I can open the properties of the project and enable or disable SSL. So that option is not possible either. Maybe it's not visible because I'm missing something, I'm not sure.

I want to see the change I made with Browser View.
None of http, https or IIS are working during the run phase. I don't know whether it's a problem with localhost or the certificate.

---

**The solutions I tried are:**

dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Uninstall IIS Express via Add Remove Program
Run command: dotnet dev-certs https --clean
Re-install IIS Express by downloading it from the Microsoft website
Run the Asp.Net application from Visual Studio
Visual studio will prompt for generating a certificate, click yes. In my case, it generated the certificate but failed to add the certificate to the trusted root with an error 'Access Denied'
Windows + R and type mmc
File > Add Snap-In
Select Certificates and click add
Select the 'Computer account' option and click finish, then click Ok.
Then expand the certificates(Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates
You will find a local host certificate with the friendly name 'ISS Express Development Certificate'
Select the certificate then cut and paste it into Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates

Below are the screenshots that I would like to show additionally.

[image: Personal Certificate]
[image: Trusted Root Certification Authorities]

### Project File Screenshot
[Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WPC5.png)

### Code Blocks

RealEstate_Dapper_UI / Properties / launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:29591",
      "sslPort": 44379
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5112",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7240;http://localhost:5112",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

The index.cshtml I want to run:

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
```

---

UI project/ Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

---

RealEstate_Dapper_Api / Properties / launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:21668",
      "sslPort": 44323
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5027",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7032;http://localhost:5027",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Debug Properties Menu Screenshots

1. [https properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Vvc.png)
2. [IIS Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkoUW.png)
3. [http properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aDpA.png)

Comment: Please post you code.  It is difficult to see what is wrong without it!

Comment: Since at an unhandled exception was recorded, you will need to iron out those in your code before getting back to VS itself, or anything related. Like the other comment indicated, your code matters a lot here. Otherwise, IIS Express shouldn't exit unexpectedly.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the codes as you said. But I cloned the project file I took as an example without making any changes. But I get the same error there too. However, the person who made the project did not make this mistake. Most likely there is a problem with my computer due to certificates or some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the property folder and the hidden `.vs` folder. Open the solution again, the launching port will be reset a new one and without swagger.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried the method you said but it didn't work.
I received a sample of the project. I pulled the repo directly from Github and when I want to run it there, I still get the same error. I think there is a problem with this on my computer.

Comment: @kaganturkay How about run the project with `dotnet run` using CMD?

Comment: @Quiand Fu That way, the project seems to be working, but what I want is the blank page in index.cshtml to appear. I'm trying to do this with view in browser.

Comment: @kaganturkay But when it is running, shouldn't the console appear an URL? You could visit the URL in the browser to see the page.

Comment: The new error I got is when I try to debug with IIS, this error appears in the browser. HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start on IIS Server

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was an issue with the developer (me) and not Visual Studio.

Using .NET 8, I didn't apply dependency injection correctly. If you add a new interface, make sure you add the appropriate AddScoped, AddSingleton, or AddTransient so DI knows how to instantiate the object. I'm unsure why I didn't look in the console log before Stack Overflow. I guess I just assumed it never even tried to launch the app. It did and failed during startup. It's a poor error message, but once I added the newly added interface and concrete class to my Startup code, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve the problem. Let me try to write down the steps I followed. Since I tried so many methods, I don't know which one is the final solution.

First of all, I only performed steps 2 and 3 of the steps [in this blog.](https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/)

After doing this, I completely removed the Visual Studio 2022 Preview version from the computer. I installed the non-preview version. In the installation step, I added all the installations that I thought might be related to IIS and SSL. I rechecked all sdks like .net 7, .net 8 sdk. I installed the hosting bundle. After following many methods one after another, localhost started to open in the same project.